# sublime text 2 shows whole HTML code inside php file in single color?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

sublime text 2 shows all my HTML code inside index.php in single color. same for other php files that contains HTML code. there is no color coding very strange! is'nt. although files containing only php code are normal.
i tried every theme and color scheme but same issue exists.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the questiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid comments (all the dashes that are highlighted in dark red), and Sublime is interpreting them as not closing, so your entire document is scoped as `comment.block.html`. Here is an image of some of your code using the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) (full disclosure: I'm its author). The italic gray text indicates a comment:

[image: PHP bad comments]

Now here is the same code using valid comments (`<!-- text here -->`):

[image: PHP fixed comments]

So, just fix your commenting style, and the syntax highlighting should work as expected.

Comment: thanks sir it works perfectly for me, and i also recommends it to others with same issue!